# Which is the correct path for AllowOverride All?

Tags: apache, drupal

My drupal uploaded to this location /var/www/drupal

If I want to add the AllowOverride All in apache2.conf

Which is the correct path?

```
<Directory /var/www/drupal>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that /var/www/drupal is the directory where you copied all the Drupal files. In that case, bot the paths are correct. There is just a difference: If you have more than one Drupal installations, for example in /var/www/drupal2 and /var/www/drupal3, then I would use the first directive you shows instead of repeating the same directive for all the directories where Drupal has been installed.

As long as the `AllowOverride All` directive is applied to the Drupal root directory or its parent, there is no practical difference between those directive. The only difference could be if somebody is able to write an .htaccess file in /var/www without your direct control, and you don't want anything bad happening because it.